# node.js/socket.io - data undefined after emitting from server to client

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So this has me banging my head against the desk. Here's the code giving me issues.

**SERVER**:

```
client.on('get-online-clients', function () {

    connection.query('SELECT CLIENTS FROM DB', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        client.emit('update-clients', rows);
        console.log(rows);
    });

});
```

**CLIENT**:

```
socket.on('update-clients', function(rows) {
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Now my issue is that when the console.log(rows) output is printed server side, in the node console, the 'rows' array is populated as expected from the result of the DB query. However, when the output from the console.log(rows) is printed client side, the 'rows' variable is undefined.

This should be such a simple piece of code, but it's getting the best of me. I have other socket emits that function almost identically to the above code, yet this particular emit is just not having it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the exact code that you're using? I haven't written anything new in Socket.io for a few months, but as you said, that looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes, it's the exact code, minus the SQL query that I've replaced. Driving me nuts.

Comment: What kind of object is rows? Socket.io should be able to handle anything, but maybe there's a small bug. Try emitting `rows.toString()` or something similar. See what you get then.

Comment: Ok, so I was messing with rows.toString(), which would send the data through fine so the client could read it, then I changed it back to rows and it's now magically working?

Comment: It's definitely not magic. Something changed. Obviously, you have your bug fixed, but I would try to track down the reason for it. In my experience, if it happens once, it'll happen again. Glad you got it working though.

Comment: I'm starting to think I had a rogue invisible character in my code, as all that has changed is that I'd rewritten the variable name manually. I'm just speculating here. Thanks for you help anyway though. Appreciate it.